# candle close higher than past 20 candles (minus the current one)

Tags: pine-script

messing around with a breakout strategy, cant figure out how to write close > highest high in last 20 candles without the current one. I think that this:

```
    hh = ta.highest(high, 20)
    if (close > hh)
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long)
```

doesnt work as the candle that closes past the range is the one becoming the highest one by definition, any tips?

cheers

Comment: Breakout of *what*? What is `high`? Where do *candles* enter what picture?

Answer (score 0):

```
hh = ta.highest(high, 20)[1]
if (close > hh)
   strategy.entry('long', strategy.long)
```